# Spring Boot + Springbox swagger error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a spring boot project want to integrate with swagger via springbox.

I have my spring boot app up and running all good.

However after I added springbox, it can not pass unit test.

Here are the details I added in project.

For `pom.xml`, added

```
  <!--Swagger io for API doc-->
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

then with a swagger config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket booksApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
            .build();
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("blah")
            .description("blah.")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("http://www.blah.com.au")
            .contact("blah")
            .build();
}

}
```

The error I am getting when run `mvn clean package` is

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/jasonfeng/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.2.2/springfox-spring-web-2.2.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

the version I am using is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Been looking into this problem for the while morning without luck, then posted this question. Just after posted the question, I found out the solution for this..... (I blame on the not-so-good morning coffee)

Simply remove the `@Configuration` annotation in the swagger configuration class.

Here is the link I refer to

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/462

Comment: you can achieve this using the answer by @Nish

Comment: When I removed the Configuration annotation, then I got pop-up: "Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served". The solution below with profiles worked.

Comment: This solved my issue but I am not sure how. Could you please explain? And is it time to discard swagger in Spring Boot projects?

Comment: Edit: By removing the @Configuraiton annotation, I must have prevented Swagger initialization while deployment, but the absence of annotation made Swagger inoperable. So basically, it is not a fix for me. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the exact same issue. Here is the solution.

Add this to application-test.properties (Create one if not already present)

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Annotate the test (if not already present)

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
```

Create a new Swagger Configuration class and annotate it as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("!test")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        .........
    }
}
```

This will make sure that swagger config is not loaded for test at all.

Comment: What does @TestPropertySource mean?

Comment: Its used to override application context loaded properties for tests. You can look at spring documentation to understand it further.

Comment: great stuff exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Profile annotation as below

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
```

so that swagger is not loaded this class not invoked during the compile/build/test life cycle
and Add the below property to application-test.properties (Create one if not already present under src/test/resources folder)
spring.profiles.active=test
resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This will solve the issue but if you make dev profile active, the issue will reappear. I have removed @Configuration annotation to solve the issue. But won't it affect how Swagger works?