# Spring Boot Swagger 2 Configuration Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, swagger

I have problems with configuration of Swagger in my Spring Boot project.
I was following the basic instruction for this, and somehow it doesn's work.

Here it is:
pom.xml

```
 <!--SWAGGER-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java Swagger Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
}
```

And i am getting this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.4.0/springfox-spring-web-2.4.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$SpringApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(SpringApplication.java:1007)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleError(SpringApplication.java:379)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:367)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:920)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at configuration.main.Application.main(Application.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:354)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:465)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93593f67.setBeanFactory(<generated>)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$EnhancedConfigurationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:442)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 39 more
```

Comment: With Spring boot, you don't need the `@Configuration`. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449612/spring-boot-springbox-swagger-error

Comment: just a hint : check endpoints if there was a duplicate value, this error will occur.

Answer (score 20):

Fixed it with removing @Configuration annotation in SwaggerConfuguration class.

Only keep @EnableSwagger2 annotation

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

P.S. My dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: that only switched from swagger3 to oas3, but did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 16):

In SpringMVC, if you want to use Swagger2,you need add '@EnableWebMvc' in you config class,like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class Swagger2Config {
   ……
}
```

Answer (score 3):

step 1: Remove the @Configuration in SwaggerConfig Class

step 2: put such code in /WEB-INF/jetty-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>

<!-- Include a swagger configuration-->
<bean name="swaggerConfig" class="com.exchangewalk.web.config.SwaggerConfig"/>
```

There are two contexts, the default spring context and the spring MVC context. If you're using the @configuration annotation, that gets picked up by the default spring context scanning which has no visibility of the RequestMappingHandlerMapping. That's why it's important that the SwaggerConfig is a bean defined in the MVC context.

For details, please refer: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/462

Comment: How can u using Swagger UI if just remove the @Configuration?

Comment: @Wuaner Please see the step 2 of my updated answer.  you have to tell MVC where is the SwaggerCofig

Comment: Thank u for prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when in pom.xml were spring-boot both dependencies for webflux and web were added:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

spring-boot-starter-webflux generated problem in that case.
I used springfox:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

For me it was enough to eliminate webflux dependency, which was added accidentally, but maybe for someone this info will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

u need additional this dependency :

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: we need below dependency as well<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Removing  @Configuration fixed my issue but swagger stopped working for obvious reason

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add this plugin to your maven.
When I was trying to run from jar, I was gettin this exception.
Then I created jar with maven->install and run that jar, there is no error .
Hope it helps you

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Spring 3, springfox-swagger-ui and springfox-swagger2 are not working properly. I have tried to solve it but no success...

So, instead of using those 2 dependencies, you can use OpenAPI 3 and this is very simple guide that I found on internet. For me, it worked on 1st time.

https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/document-spring-rest-api-with-openapi-3swagger/

Hope you can solve this issue.